# Prettier settings to format object-destructuring until end of the line, instead of new line for every property

Tags: javascript, object, visual-studio-code, prettier, object-destructuring

instead of this
[image]
do this
[image]

It could take only 2 lines not making my file longer than needed.

Comment: All of Prettier's options are listed here: https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html. The point of the tool is to *not* spend time thinking about how the code should be laid out.

Comment: It's a valid question, but generally prettier is an "opinionated" formatter so it decides everything for you.  I think it makes the code ugly and unreadable because the code should be consistent bases on other blocks in the file, not on a line by line bases.  We also all have big 4k monitors these days, and the 80 character line limit is a waste of space.

Comment: I also think it is a valid question, but I think the user's example seems like a situation where they can add `// prettier-ignore` comments. We use them only sparingly in my projects.